# Local variables in Python

Tags: python

I wrote this small program to print multiplication tables. I was understanding the local variables then I added two variables with same name in each function. but it is running and I am not getting any 2 variables with same name error. Please help me understand the idea here -

```
def printMultiples(n):
    i = 1
    i = 5
    while i <= 10:
        print n*i, '\t',
        i = i + 1
    print

def printMultTable():
    i = 1
    i = 10
    while i <= 10:
        printMultiples(i)
        i = i + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

The variable `i` gets defined as soon as the function is run, it does not wait until the lines

```
i = 1
i = 10
```

are run. When the code is compiled, Python looks at every variable that is assigned in the function, and creates definitions for any that aren't declared to be `global` or `nonlocal`.

Each `i =` line will just change the value, it doesn't cause it to be defined again.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what's happening in your script:

```
i = 1
```

creates the variable `i` and assigns the value 1 to it

```
i = 5
```

replaces the value held in `i` with 5

```
while i <= 10:
```

starts your loop

```
    print n*i, '\t',
```

The first iteration of the loop will print n * 5 and a tab character

```
    i = i + 1
```

increments i by one

Comment: You won't actually get a `NameError`, because `n` is a function parameter.

Answer (score 1):

There aren't two variables with the same name, there's one variable that is being assigned to twice.

```
i = 1  # i is declared and assigned to 1
i = 5  # the same i is reassigned to 5
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not actually creating two variables with the same name; your second `i =` is reassigning `i` to a new value, same as `i = i + 1` is setting `i` to the value of `i + 1`.

There are more Pythonic ways to deal with looping a fixed number of times, by the way:

```
for i in range(1, 11):
    printMultiples(i)
```

This will execute `printMultiples` for values starting in 1 and less than 11.

Answer (score 1):

In python, symbols are just names for variables.  They are do not allocate memory as they do for say, C/C++.  So what you are doing is simply reassigning the values to 'i' in each case.